# Horizontal step scroll for variable amount

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have page with two buttons (scroll left and scroll right), and on click, page have to go left and right by div width (every div have different width). Could this be done with jQuery? I don't know how to read current div id (one close to left side of border), and how to define scroll (left or right) by width of previous/next div?

Comment: Can you post your HTML code and also the script that you have tried?

Comment: html test page: http://kbt.desimir.com/testscroll.html, code din't even try, I don't have idea how to start... :(

Comment: What you mean by saying 'page' ? what page? some DIVs container or the whole document?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precise: I have to scroll wrapper div content (say 10 divs of variable width), left or right for variable amount (div width) by clicking on buttons for left/right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click just increase, decrease a Counter `var c`.
 This will help us to target the desired DIV by `.eq( c )`
Than all we need is to get the desired DIV `.offset().left` and move the page to that position:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/otadex/43/edit)*

HTML (add a .box to your DIVs):

```
<div class="box" id="01" style="width:200px; height:100px; border:solid 1px; float:left">div01</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

  var c = 0;
  var boxN = $('.box').length;
  
  $('#left, #right').on('click', function( e ){
    
    e.preventDefault();
   
    c = this.id=='right' ? ++c%boxN : --c ;
    if(c<0){ c=boxN-1; }
    var boxL = $('.box').eq( c ).offset().left;
    
    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollLeft: boxL});
    
    
  });
  
});
```

Comment: I think this could solve my problem, I have to try this. Right now I don't have time, but I'll definitely try this... Thanks!

Comment: Another question (maybe you'll know...) I use code above, it worked like a charm, but in webkit based browser (Chrome, Safari), but in Firefox do not? Maybe you know did I miss something? there is work in progress on http://rr.desimir.com/adg/adghome.html with this jquery implemented...

Comment: @desko try with `$('#mainwrap').stop().animate({scrollLeft: boxL});`

Comment: I try, no response whatsoever... :(
Also, with #mainwrap instead of body, script in Chrome stop working...
Could that be something about jquery version?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about some kind of slider then you have a containerdiv and an innerdiv with the total length of the items contained within.

The containerdiv will have overflow hidden

Next you control the position of the divs

This is just one way of thinking...

Comment: I don't need to hide content, just have to position current div to leftmost position, and on click to go to previous or next, so left side of this div have to be aligned with container left side, visibility of other divs is not an issue